# Discordpy Mod Logs Command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a mod logs, I'm not really good at this, I scripted myself and kinda worked but it didn't worked. So basically my plan is when someone types .modlogs #channel, bot is gonna get the channel id and type it to json file with guild id, i made that it works very well I'm stuck on getting key info from json file, im printing the values and they are same.

```
@commands.command(aliases=['purge'])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self,ctx, arg: int = None):
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.send(':x: You need to state a value!')
    else:
        with open('./logs.json', 'r') as f:
            logsf = json.load(f)
        if ctx.guild.id in logsf:
            embedv = discord.Embed(color = discord.Colour.random())
            embedv.add_field(name='Event Type:', value="Clear")
            embedv.add_field(name='Channel:', value= ctx.channel)
            embedv.add_field(name='Moderator:', value=ctx.message.author)
            embedv.footer(text='Epifiz Logging')
            schannel = commands.get_channel(logsf[ctx.guild.id])
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=arg)
            await discord.schannel.send(embed=embedv)
            await ctx.send('Done')
        elif ctx.guild.id not in logsf:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=arg)
            await ctx.send(':white_check_mark: Successfully cleared {} messages.'.format(arg))
```

also my json file:

```
{
"838355243817369620": 853297044922564608
}
```

Also guild id is on json file, its not wrong.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDhjf.png)

Comment: Your json dict has a string as key, while ctx.guild.id is an int. To fix this you have two options: either make your keys back to ints when loading your json(with an object_hook function) or make your ctx.guild.id into a str every time you need it

Comment: How I'm gonna make my keys int?

Comment: with the object_hook keyword in json.load(), like: data = json.load(f, object_hook=convert_keys_to_int) for the convert_keys_to_int i use... forgive the formatting: def convert_keys_to_int(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            new_key = int(k)
        except ValueError:
            new_key = k
        if type(v) == dict:
            v = convert_keys_to_int(v)
        new_dict[new_key] = v
    return new_dict

Comment: Thank you, I solved it.

Comment: No problem, note that all your keys will be converted to ints if possible with that function, so if you have any keys that are strings but can be converted to ints it will convert them and possibly break your program

Answer (score 0):

You made multiple mistakes in your code. The reason why you are getting the error is because this line here `if ctx.guild.id in logsf:` returns `False` even if the guild's id is in your JSON file. Here is why:

1. `logsf = json.load(f)` returns a dictionary. You'll get `{"838355243817369620": 853297044922564608}` it's unclear whether `838355243817369620` or `853297044922564608` is your guild id but think of it this way:

> `s = {1:2}`

> `2 in s` return `False`

and the second mistake is inserting `"838355243817369620"` as a `str` rather than an `int` like this `838355243817369620`.

The solution is to use `list()` as follow `if ctx.guild.id in list(logsf):` and to insert `"838355243817369620"` as an int in your JSON file so it looks like this:

```
{
838355243817369620: 853297044922564608
}
#rather than this
{
"838355243817369620": 853297044922564608
}
```

2. `value` in embeds accepts str not discord objects. Use `f"{input}"` rather than the object as an input.

> embedv.add_field(name='Channel:', value= f"{ctx.channel}")
>
> embedv.add_field(name='Moderator:', value=f"{ctx.message.author}")

3. `await schannel.send(embed=embedv)` rather than `await discord.schannel.send(embed=embedv)`
4. From this line `schannel = commands.get_channel(logsf[ctx.guild.id])` I can assume that `838355243817369620` is your server's id. So, I think that you can use:

> `if ctx.guild.id in logsf.keys():` instead of `if ctx.guild.id in list(logsf):`

and make sure to convert its keys values into `int` rather than `str` to make it work.